# Firestore Data Modelling

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My app has two Firestore Collection:

- Events (collection)
  Document

  - eventId
  - hostId (userId of organizer)
  - title
  - etc.
- Users  (Collection)
  Document

  - userId
  - friends (array of userId's)
  - age
  - etc.

I would like for a user to query all events created by his friends.

I considered

- do a seperate query for each friend and pull each friend events. This could get ugly with sorting on dates.
- adding a hostFriends field in the event and use an array-contains user's Id query. But this will be problematic if someone add a friend after having created an event. I would have to sync this across continiously..
- doing client side filtering, but this will lead to many unneccesary reads..

Would be happy to hear any additional idea's or if one of the above would make sense? many many thanks!

This is my first post, apologies if I made any formatting mistakes.

Comment: Have you found a solution?